# conversion from java code to pl sql package

Tags: java, plsql

I have java classes and I want to convert them to pl sql packages. are there any tools(open source or commercial) available to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no but oracle allows you to use java stored procedures, may be you can consider them.